# How can I 'force' ALL karma test to fail if an eslint error is found?

Tags: unit-testing, karma-runner, eslint

I have found that sometimes people do not realise they have linting errors in their tests when they run them since they are show before the test progress/information.

Is there any configuration which will cause ALL tests to fail if any of the tests have any linting errors?

I am using mocha with karma.

Thanks.

Comment: Alternatively, is there any eslint configuration option that will cause the build to fail when linting errors are found?

Answer (score 2):

Make the `ESLint` execution a part of the `grunt` or `gulp` or "npm" task (whichever you use). For instance, when we run `grunt test`, first the `ESLint` is executed and then `karma`. If there are any errors or warnings produced by `ESLint` the task would fail early.

Comment: I'm using webpack, it's configured so that eslint does run first...and it fails that particular unit test. But karma still runs, and the remaining unit tests pass

Comment: @Pmmoks have not used webpack, but I guess there should be a "fail fast" option, meaning it should fail a task if a subtask fails, this kind of behavior should be configurable. In grunt, for example, this is the default behavior and you can "force" it to ignore the errors in subtasks separately.

Answer (score 1):

Inside you webpack config, setup fail option for eslint like this

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "...",
  module: {
    // ...
  },
  eslint: {
    failOnError: true
  }
}
```

This would fail the build.

**Doc ref:** https://github.com/MoOx/eslint-loader#failonerror-default-false