# Make Karma fail test on syntax error

Tags: karma-runner, test-runner

When a test of ours has a syntax error we get something like this:

```
WARNING in ./tests/components/RequesterInfo/RequsterInfo.spec.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Volumes/dev/VisualforceCore/tests/components/RequesterInfo/RequsterInfo.spec.js: Unexpected token, expected , (34:39)
  32 |             TimeZoneSidKey: 'America/Indiana/Indianapolis',
  33 |             Title: 'CTO',
> 34 |             SatisfactionLevel__c: value: 'Low',
     |                                        ^
  35 |           }
  36 |           fieldSet: {
  37 |             LanguageLocaleKey: { label: 'Language' },
```

We often miss this error as it gets swallowed up in all the output
Can I make karma fail on a syntax error?

Comment: Common practice is to use a linter like jshint or eslint to validate syntax before the tests start to execute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I 'force' ALL karma test to fail if an eslint error is found?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39229441/how-can-i-force-all-karma-test-to-fail-if-an-eslint-error-is-found)